# Get Active Shell in SWT, even if the Shell is not on focus

Tags: java, windows, swt

`Display.getActiveShell()` seems to only consider a Shell as active if it's focused. If at the moment another application has focus that means `Display.getActiveShell()` returns `null`.

I need a method that will always tell me which is the Shell on focus on my SWT application, even when my SWT application is not on focus.

I've quickly hacked this piece of code together, although sometimes I get an `AssertionException`:

```
public static Shell getActiveShell() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell result = display.getActiveShell();

    if (result == null) {
        Shell[] shells = display.getShells();
        for (Shell shell : shells) {
            if (shell.getShells().length == 0) {
                if (result != null)
                    throw new AssertionException();
                result = shell;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is there any standard way to approach this issue other than writing your own method?

Comment: _"I need a method that will always tell me which is the Shell on focus on my SWT application, even when my SWT application is not on focus."_ the second part is contradicting the first. Can you clarify?

Comment: One thing is to have a shell on focus on my application's context, another thing is to have my swt application on focus!

Comment: There is no focus within your application if the application itself does not have the focus.

Comment: There must be some shell that is at least on top of the others? the canonical case being when you have a shell(or dialog or wtv) that doesn't allow you to click in any other shell in the application until its gone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recently, I had a similar problem and though you probably found a solution in the meanwhile, I'd like to share mine for future reference.

The `ShellActivationTracker` adds a display filter that listens for `Activate` events and - if the activated widget is a `Shell` - remembers the most recently activated `Shell`. Thus you can query the (last) active shell even if your application is currently not active/focused.

```
class ShellActivationTracker implements Listener {
  Shell activeShell;

  ShellActivationTracker(Display display) {
    activeShell = display.getActiveShell();
    display.addFilter(SWT.Activate, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.widget instanceof Shell) {
      activeShell = (Shell)event.widget;
    }
  }
}
```